# meta description tag automatically

Tags: blogger

I am trying to add meta tag for description when it is missing in the **posts**. I want first 150 characters to be considered as description. I tried with multiple methods but does not work.

**1st Method**

```
<b:tag name='script' type='text/javascript'> 

var msg = &quot;<b:eval expr='snippet(data:post.body, {length: 150, links: false})'/>&quot;;  
var metaDescription = document.head.children.description;
if (metaDescription == null) {
  metaDescription = document.createElement(&#39;meta&#39;);
  metaDescription.name = &#39;description&#39;;
  document.head.append(metaDescription);
}
metaDescription.content = msg;
console.log(msg);  
  
</b:tag>
```

**2nd Method**

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription == &quot;&quot;'>
         <meta expr:content='data:post.longSnippet' name='description'/>
        </b:if>      
      </b:if>
```

**3rd Method**

```
  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription == &quot;&quot;'>
     <meta expr:content='snippet(data:post.body, {length: 150, links: false})' name='description'/>
    </b:if>      
  </b:if>
```

Comment: I really wouldn't do this. Search engines are pretty good at generating descriptions of pages automatically. Their algorithms are much better than "grab the first 150 characters". It's one thing to manually craft a description you think is better, but doing it programmatically is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

```
<b:eval expr='data:post.body snippet { length: 140 }'/>
```

example:  https://skeleton001.blogspot.com/

[image]

source: https://geekthis.net/post/blogger-theme-data-tags-for-widgets/